# Replace duplicates items in array with different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, replace, lodash

i would like to Replace duplicates items with different values.

eg `arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]` i want to replace the duplicates with `R`

So the result looks like this   `arr = [1,R,R,R,2,R,R,3]`

right now I'm using this approach:

```
    arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]
    let previous = 0;
    let current = 1;
    while (current < arr.length) {
        if (arr[previous] === arr[current]) {
            arr[current] = 'R';
            current += 1;
        } else if (arr[previous] !== arr[current]) {
            previous = current;
            current += 1;
        }
    }
```

i wondering if there is different approach for to achieve that.  for Example  using Lodash (uniqwith, uniq).

Thanks

Comment: Keep a set or a map of everything you've encountered and when a duplicate is found, replace it.

Comment: do you want to replace only the same value in direct neighborhood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's how I'd do it
It look if the current element is the first of the array with the current value and replace it if not

It may take some times on very big arrays

```js
const input = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]
let output = input.map(
  (el, i) => input.indexOf(el) === i ? el : 'R'
)
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a closure over a `Set` and check if the value is already seen or not.

```js
let array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
    result = array.map((seen => v => seen.has(v) ? 'R' : (seen.add(v), v))(new Set));

console.log(...result);
```

A *check previous value* approach

```js
let array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
    result = array.map((v, i, { [i - 1]: l }) => l === v ? 'R' : v);

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but I find it very, very hard to read (even with years of experience with JavaScript). I don't know how helpful it could be for someone who is just starting to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple to do by using sets ([Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)).

```js
const initialArray = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3];
const valuesSet = new Set();

const newArray = initialArray.map((value) => {
    if (valuesSet.has(value)) {
        return 'R';
    } else {
        valuesSet.add(value);
        return value;
    }
});
```